# How to define the default code when creating a new C# Class with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Making a new class in VS10 gives me

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Foo
{
    class Bar
    {
    }
}
```

Is it possible to setup VS10 so I get this instead?

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class Bar
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can modify it. See [this article](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/02/17/how-to-modify-the-default-new-class-template-in-visual-studio-2008/) for a decent walk-through.

Here's a snip-it from the article that explains where to find the template:

**Step One - find the template**

> **Visual Studio 2010**
>
> **64 bit:**
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip
>
> **32 bit:**
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip

**Step Two - modify the template**

> Extract the zip file.
>
> Using a text editor, open the Class.cs file.
>
> Save the file.
>
> Rebuild the zip file with the new Class.cs.  Be careful to build the
> zip file correctly.
>
> Copy the new zip file back here and overwrite the existing one

**Step Three - update VS**

> Open a command prompt as Administrator.
>
> Change to the appropriate directory and run command:
>
> **devenv.exe /installvstemplates**

Comment: What happens if that link moves?

Comment: @ChrisF: Then you can use Wayback Machine ;)

Comment: @ChrisF, links are part of answers. There is no use in re-inventing the wheel. When an article is involved, I'm not going to re-create it on SO. With that being said, you'll never see me posting **just** a link.

Comment: James - Yes links are part of answer - to **back up** what you post as the answer. I agree that re-inventing the wheel is bad, but part of what makes Stack Exchange great is that questions and answers are self contained.

Comment: Thanks for the answers James and btlog, i'll try it out as soon as I got some time.

Comment: Now it's 2021, do you know how to achieve this with new VS ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. This MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s365byhx.aspx has links to several approaches to achieve this.

I think the easiest way is to make a file with the template that you want, substitue parameters and export the template. In your example create a new class with the existing template

```
 namespace Foo
 {
     public class Bar
     {
     }
 }
```

Swap out the variable parts of this. ie the namespace name 'Foo' and the class name 'Bar'

```
 namespace $rootnamespace$
 {
     public class $safeitemrootname$
     {
     }
 }
```

Save the change

- You can now go File -> Export Template. Select Item Template (click
  Next)
- Select the file you created for this example (click Next)
- Select any item references you want to add to the project. In this
  case there aren't any (click next)
- Enter a Template Name (ie PublicClass). This is what the file will
  be called in the new file dialog. Also what the default file will
  be called on creation

This will create a zip file in {userpath}/My Documents/Visual Studio 2010/My Exported Templates. You do not need to run as admin or run any other tools. VS will automatically pull this up from the this path.

I realise this doesn't replace the existing option. If you want to do this I would use the same process, use the same Item Name as the default Item Name. In this case class. I would use the path and registration process defined by @James Hill

Comment: What happens if that link moves?

Comment: @ChrisF, lots of your answers reference MSDN. Has a link offended you today :-)?

Comment: @James Hill and btlog: [We do prefer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I think the folks at Microsoft go out of their way to make sure the links in MSDN change frequently. Sometimes google can't even keep up with the changes they make.